# Mounting Ceiling fan in 1940s built home

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, support

I am trying to mount ceiling fans in several rooms of a very old home. I have found pictures of other J boxes on this forum that appear very similar to mine so I attached someone else's picture so you have an idea of what the current J box and wiring looks like.

[image: old Jbox w/ wiring]

It was recommended by an electrician friend that I put a 2x4 between studs in the attic and screw the original box to the stud, rather than putting an entirely new J box in.  His reasoning was that by the time I pull the wires out of the old Jbox and put them in the new one, I will likely have crumbled off some insulation and cause new problems. The old wires are very brittle.

That seems reasonable, however, there is no obvious way to mount the ceiling fan to the original Jbox, once it's been secured.

I came accross another forum post where someone showed a threaded nipple with an adapter plate, which I should be able mount the fan to. I've never seen any of these but it seems reasonable.

[image: Threaded nipple + adapter plate]

Does this appear to be the right way to do things? I just need to secure the backside of the Jbox to a 2x4 mounted to studs in the attic, and then thread the adapter plate in from the room underneath, and then mount fan to adapter plate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are all kinds of hack jobs out there to install ceiling fans. Code states that ceiling fans be installed using a fan rated junction box. The boxes will be stamped inside that they are approved for ceiling fans.

**If the wiring is that crumbly, it should be corrected or replaced.**

Since you have attic access, that shouldn't be too hard. The adapter plate you have is meant to be used for hanging a light fixture, not a ceiling fan. The screw threads in that adapter and non ceiling fan junction boxes will not support the weight of a fan. Do this right. You don't want to be under one when it falls.

Comment: edited to not be wall'o text and to add a bit of emphasis. +1

Comment: @FreeMan  I like that...